# PHP: How To Create A Dynamic Variable Within a Class

Tags: php, class, variables, dynamic

Alright so I think this may be extremely basic, but it has me stumped nonetheless. Before I get to my question, let me demonstrate the concept my question is based on with this *working* example:

```
<?php

$a = 'Stack';
$b = $a.' Overflow';
echo $b; // Result: "Stack Overflow"

?>
```

In the above example, `$b` is defined as the combination of `$a` and `' Overflow'`.
Now, let's assume I want to do the same thing as above *except* I don't want to use global variables. I want to use classes. This is how I have attempted to achieve that:

```
<?php

class ClassName {
    public $a = 'Stack';
    public $b = $this->a.' Overflow'; // This gives me: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$this'"
}

$instantiate = new ClassName;
echo $instantiate->$b; // Desired result: "Stack Overflow"

?>
```

As stated, this attempt results in an error. To me, this attempt seems logical, but I guess PHP doesn't think so.

**Question:** Is this possible, and if so, how do I go about achieving the desired result? Also, if you could explain why my attempt has failed (logically), that would be a bonus.

I've searched and researched for hours on end trying to find an answer or figure this out on my own, but for the life of me, I cannot find anyone or anything that even touches on this (including other Stack Overflow threads). I can't even find anywhere saying it's impossible or anything of the sort either.

I'm a PHP novice, so I may need more explanation than others, but any kind of help or general guidance would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use $this when defining the class because it refers to a concrete object context which becomes available after instantiation. You can use a constructor for that kinds of stuff.

```
class ClassName 
    {
        public $a = 'Stack';
        public $b = "";
        function __construct()
        {
          $this->b = $this->a.' Overflow'; 
        }
    }

$instantiate = new ClassName;
echo $instantiate->b;
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried it, but unfortunately it still doesn't work for me... I've updated my post with the errors it gave me.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. try `$instantiate->b` instead of `$instantiate->$b`.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from the [PHP Docs about defining class properties](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)

> They are defined by using one of the keywords public, protected, or private, followed by a normal variable declaration. This declaration may include an initialization, **but this initialization must be a constant value** -- that is, **it must be able to be evaluated at compile time** and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

(my emphasis)

Concatenation cannot be evaluated at compile time, only at run time.

---

If you need to do this, then define the initial value for the property in the constructor

Answer (score 0):

This would throw a syntax error because you are using `$this` in a scope that it is not [allowed](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) to:

> The pseudo-variable $this is available inside any class method when that method is called from within an object context. $this is a reference to the calling object (usually the object to which the method belongs, but possibly another object, if the method is called statically from the context of a secondary object).

This means, even if you wanted you won't be able to do what you want to do because of such restriction. This is a common restriction that is in many programming languages, properties have to be initialized to static values. To solve your issue you can do any of the following:

- In your constructor, create those variables.
- Create the second variable on its own, and create a method that concatenates the two.
- Create a magic method to do it for you.

The same restriction holds true for static class properties.